# Selected mailbox information missing in exported CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, exchange-server

I have been trying to export some mailbox statistics to Excel with `Export-Csv`. This is the script I came up with, but now I'm at a dead end:

```
Get-Mailbox |
    select DisplayName, Alias, Database, TotalItemSize, ItemCount,
           StorageLimitStatus, IssueWarningQuota, ProhibitSendQuota |
    Export-Csv c:\xyz.csv
```

The problem I'm having is that it exports everything except `TotalItemSize`, `ItemCount` and `StorageLimitStatus` into the .csv file. I don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object that `Get-Mailbox` returns doesn't not contain the property's you are trying to select. If you run the following command you will see a list of all properties available that `Get-Mailbox` can return.

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
```

You will want to use `Get-MailboxStatistics` to get those properties:

```
Get-Mailbox "Your.Mailbox" | Get-MailboxStatistics |
    Select TotalItemSize, ItemCount, StorageLimitStatus
```

To get all the properties into the csv file you could create a custom object and export that:

```
Get-mailbox "Your.Mailbox" | %{
    $mb = $_
    $stats = $mb | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select TotalItemSize,ItemCount,StorageLimitStatus

    $Properties = @{ 
          DisplayName = $mb.DisplayName 
          Alias = $mb.Alias
          Database = $mb.Database
          IssueWarningQuota = $mb.IssueWarningQuota
          ProhibitSendQuota=$mb.ProhibitSendQuota
          TotalItemSize=$stats.TotalItemSize
          ItemCount=$stats.ItemCount
          StorageLimitStatus=$stats.StorageLimitStatus
    }

    New-Object psobject -Property $properties
} | Export-Csv c:\xyz.csv
```

Comment: So would I have to add the Get-MailboxStatistics results separately?